# Jquery or HTML problem? Why isn't my selector working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

The following function does not produce an alert when I click on the 'overview_table_header' class. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class='overview_table_wrapper'> 
      <table> 
        <thead> 
          <tr> 
            <th class='col_1'> 
              <span class='overview_table_header' data-sort='DESC'> 
                Contest
              </span> 
              <span class='arrow'>></span> 
            </th> 
            <th class='col_2'> 
              <span class='overview_table_header' data-sort='DESC'> 
                Tweets
              </span> 
              <span class='arrow'></span> 
            </th> 
            <th class='col_3'> 
              <span class='overview_table_header' data-sort='DESC'> 
                Starts
              </span> 
              <span class='arrow'></span> 
            </th> 
            <th class='col_4'> 
              <span class='overview_table_header' data-sort='DESC'> 
                Ends
              </span> 
              <span class='arrow'></span> 
            </th> 
          </tr> 
        </thead>
```

.js file:

(I'm loading this file above not shown; other jquery works from this file)

```
$('.overview_table_header').click(function() {
alert("clicked!");
});
```

Comment: This should work. Can you reproduce the failure on a JSFiddle?

Comment: Are there actually script tags in your real code?

Comment: No this isn't a direct copy paste. This is in another file

Comment: @JZ: Are you including the file at in the `head` or after the table?

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/KgXdU/1/

Comment: Are you missing a closing </table></div> after the final </thead>? Anyway, you should wrap javascript code inside <script>..code..</script> tags

Comment: From that snippet of code, quite a lot..? Your jQuery code (presuming since it looks like jQuery) isn't within a `<script type="javascript"></script>` block, you don't use `$(document).ready(function() {});` and your HTML is also mixed with you JavaScript. I think you'll need to include more code, please.

Comment: @stealthyninja: You don't have to put the code in `ready` handler if it comes after the HTML element it refers to.

Comment: does the '<span class="overview_table_header">' appear after the DOM is first loaded? You might need to delegate the click event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Make sure jQuery.js is included in the page(before the code snippet below).
2) Add the click binding in the ready event and add Script tags

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
   $('.overview_table_header').click(function() { alert("clicked!"); });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: You are correct; the "ready event" is missing!  Lines 2 and 4.  You can use either `$(document).ready(function(){` as Eddie said, or the shortcut version `$(function(){` as you see here.

Answer (score 1):

Put this part in your head tag of the page

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.overview_table_header').click(function() {
        alert("clicked!");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how exactly you have structured your code, but here is a structure that works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>jQuery Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Geany 0.20" />
    <script type="text/Javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/Javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.overview_table_header').click(function() {
                alert("clicked!");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class='overview_table_wrapper'> 
          <table> 
            <thead> 
              <tr> 
                <th class='col_1'> 
                  <span class='overview_table_header' data-sort='DESC'> 
                    Contest
                  </span> 
                  <span class='arrow'>></span> 
                </th> 
                <th class='col_2'> 
                  <span class='overview_table_header' data-sort='DESC'> 
                    Tweets
                  </span> 
                  <span class='arrow'></span> 
                </th> 
                <th class='col_3'> 
                  <span class='overview_table_header' data-sort='DESC'> 
                    Starts
                  </span> 
                  <span class='arrow'></span> 
                </th> 
                <th class='col_4'> 
                  <span class='overview_table_header' data-sort='DESC'> 
                    Ends
                  </span> 
                  <span class='arrow'></span> 
                </th> 
              </tr> 
            </thead> 
    </div>  
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

With what you've provided us this should work fine, but I'm thinking that perhaps this table is also generated with javascript?  If so you'll need to use the delegate method to assign listeners to these span tags

```
<script>
$('.overview_table_wrapper').delegate('.overview_table_header','click', function() {
alert("clicked!");
});
</script>
```